# Структура данных, поддерживающая быструю вставку и вычисление медианы

Tags: java, алгоритм, оптимизация, структуры-данных

Мне нужна структура данных, которая поддерживает следующие операции:

1. Вставить число;
2. Найти медиану всех вставленных чисел;
3. (дополнительно) Найти заранее известный квантиль (0-1) всех
   вставленных чисел;

Самый простой способ - сортировка чисел после каждой вставки, но это не быстро. Есть ли более быстрое решение?

Comment: Без пункта 3) можно использовать две бинарных кучи - minheap и maxheap, поддерживая размер куч равным.

Answer (score 5):

Самый быстрый вариант в смысле поиска и добавления это бинарное поисковое дерево.

- Вставка O(logN)
- поиск медианы O(logN)
- поиск квантиля (выводится из медианы) O(logN)

Создание [бинарного дерева](https://acm.bsu.by/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2) на Java

[Поиск медианы](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-median-bst-time-o1-space/) в бинарном дереве.

Answer (score 3):

*Что такое "быстро" - каждый понимал по-своему. A.Гайдар "Чук и Гек"*

Вставляйте сразу на нужное место, тогда сортировать ничего не придется. Вставка в сортированный список - `O(logN)`.

Comment: Про сдвиг `N/2` элементов не забыли?